# Почему на странице загрузки Java до сих пор рекомендуют скачать 8 версию?

Tags: java

Я разрабатываю приложение на JavaFx и доступен уже редактор основанный на 10 Java, а до сей поры приходится все делать на 8, только потому что нет публикации для загрузки джава 10 или 9 для обычных пользователей.

Вроде бы такой политики у джава раньше не было и как только выходила новая версия, старая считалась уже устаревшей. Что поменялось и почему так происходит сейчас?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

С марта 2017-го Java перешла на быстрый релизный цикл - каждый квартал update-релиз, каждые полгода feature-релиз и раз в 3 года LTS-релиз. Конечному пользователю Oracle предлагает именно LTS-релизы. С сентября на странице https://java.com/ru/download/ будет предлагаться уже Java 11.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что после 11 версии, следующую они будут предлагать уже аж 17 версию через три года?

Comment: Да, скорее всего.